# How can I start conversation only if the object has finished scaling up?

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

The scaling script :

```
using System.Collections;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using UnityEngine;

public class Scaling : UnityEngine.MonoBehaviour
{
    public GameObject objectToScale;
    public GameObject lookAtTarget;
    public float duration = 1f;
    public Vector3 minSize;
    public Vector3 maxSize;
    public bool scaleUp = false;
    public Coroutine scaleCoroutine;

    [HideInInspector]
    public bool scaledFinishedUp = false;

    [HideInInspector]
    public bool scaledFinishedDown = false;

    public void Inits()
    {
        objectToScale.transform.localScale = minSize;
    }

    public IEnumerator scaleOverTime(GameObject targetObj, Vector3 toScale, float duration, Camera objectToScaleCamera)
    {
        float counter = 0;
        Vector3 startScaleSize = targetObj.transform.localScale;

        while (counter < duration)
        {
            counter += Time.deltaTime;
            targetObj.transform.localScale = Vector3.Lerp(startScaleSize, toScale, counter / duration);

            if (scaleUp)
            {
                var lookPos = lookAtTarget.transform.position - objectToScale.transform.position;
                lookPos.y = 0;
                var rotation = Quaternion.LookRotation(lookPos);
                objectToScale.transform.rotation = Quaternion.Slerp(objectToScale.transform.rotation, rotation, counter / duration);
            }
            else
            {
                var lookPos = lookAtTarget.transform.position - objectToScale.transform.position;
                lookPos.y = 0;
                var rotation = Quaternion.LookRotation(objectToScaleCamera.transform.forward);//SwitchCameras.GetCurrentCamera().transform.forward);//Camera.main.transform.forward);
                objectToScale.transform.rotation = Quaternion.Slerp(objectToScale.transform.rotation, rotation, counter / duration);
            }

            yield return null;
        }

        if(objectToScale.transform.localScale.x >= maxSize.x
            && objectToScale.transform.localScale.y >= maxSize.y
            && objectToScale.transform.localScale.z >= maxSize.z)
        {
            scaledFinishedUp = true;
        }

        if (objectToScale.transform.localScale.x <= maxSize.x
            && objectToScale.transform.localScale.y <= maxSize.y
            && objectToScale.transform.localScale.z <= maxSize.z)
        {
            scaledFinishedDown = true;
        }
    }

    public IEnumerator scaleOverTime(GameObject targetObj, Vector3 toScale, float duration, float rotationSpeed)
    {
        float counter = 0;
        Vector3 startScaleSize = targetObj.transform.localScale;

        while (counter < duration)
        {
            counter += Time.deltaTime;
            targetObj.transform.localScale = Vector3.Lerp(startScaleSize, toScale, counter / duration);

            targetObj.transform.Rotate(Vector3.up * rotationSpeed * Time.deltaTime, Space.Self);

            yield return null;
        }
    }
}
```

And the script with the conversations :

```
using System;
using System.Collections;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using UnityEngine;
using UnityEngine.AI;

public class NaviDialogue : MonoBehaviour
{
    public ObjectsManipulation op;
    public bool scale = true;
    public Scaling scaling;
    public ConversationTrigger conversationTrigger;

    private void Start()
    {
        op.canScale = false;
    }

    private void Update()
    {
        if (scaling == true && DOFControl.hasFinished == true)
        {
            DOFControl.hasFinished = false;
            PlayerController.disablePlayerController = true;
            NaviConversations(0);
        }
    }

    public void NaviConversations(int Index)
    {
        scaling.scaleUp = true;
        op.Scaling(false);
        StartCoroutine(conversationTrigger.PlayConversation(Index));
    }
}
```

Just after the line :

```
op.Scaling(false);
```

I want to check if the object has finished scaling up then start the StartCoroutine. The problem is that in the Update I'm calling NaviConversations only once.

And then when the StartCoroutine has finished I want to do something else like this : This will scale down back the object :

```
scaling.scaleUp = false;
op.Scaling(false);
```

And last the class with the PlayConversatio method :

```
using System;
using System.Collections;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.IO;
using System.Linq;
using UnityEditor;
using UnityEngine;

public class ConversationTrigger : MonoBehaviour
{
    public List<Conversation> conversations = new List<Conversation>();
    public GameObject canvas;

    [HideInInspector]
    public static int conversationIndex;

    public bool conversationEnd = false;

    private bool activateButton = false;
    private DialogueManager dialoguemanager;
    private bool startDialogue = false;

    private void Start()
    {
        conversationIndex = 0;
        dialoguemanager = FindObjectOfType<DialogueManager>();
    }

    public IEnumerator PlayConversation(int index)
    {
        if (conversations.Count > 0 &&
            conversations[index].Dialogues.Count > 0)
        {
            for (int i = 0; i < conversations[index].Dialogues.Count; i++)
            {
                if (dialoguemanager != null)
                {
                    dialoguemanager.StartDialogue(conversations[index].Dialogues[i]);
                }

                while (DialogueManager.dialogueEnded == false)
                {
                    yield return null;
                }
            }

            conversationIndex = index;
            conversationEnd = true;
            canvas.SetActive(false);
            Debug.Log("Conversation Ended");
        }
    }

    public void SaveConversations()
    {
        string jsonTransform = JsonHelper.ToJson(conversations.ToArray(), true);
        File.WriteAllText(@"d:\json.txt", jsonTransform);
    }

    public void LoadConversations()
    {
        string jsonTransform = File.ReadAllText(@"d:\json.txt");
        conversations.Clear();
        conversations.AddRange(JsonHelper.FromJson<Conversation>(jsonTransform));
    } 
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't see what happens in

`conversationTrigger.PlayConversation(Index)` but you could use [`WaitUntil`](https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/WaitUntil.html) to the top of it in order to make it wait until the scaling ends.

Something like

```
yield return new WaitUntil(scalingIsDoneCondition);
```

where `scalingIsDoneCondition` is the check whether the scaling has finished. As soon as it returns `true` the Coroutine continues.

---

Alternatively you can have an additional IEnumerator and wait there like e.g.

```
public void NaviConversations(int Index)
{
    scaling.scaleUp = true;
    op.Scaling(false);
    StartCoroutine(StartConversationAfterScaling(Index));
}

private IEnumerator StartConversationAfterScaling(int index)
{
    yield return new WaitUntil(scalingIsDoneCondition);

    StartCoroutine(conversationTrigger.PlayConversation(Index));
}
```

If you needed to check the condition from within the same class.

---

Another form is making the whole scaling rather a `public IEnumerator` and yield it from the other one

```
public void NaviConversations(int Index)
{
    scaling.scaleUp = true;
    StartCoroutine(StartConversationAfterScaling(Index));
}

private IEnumerator StartConversationAfterScaling(int index)
{
    yield return op.Scaling(false);

    StartCoroutine(conversationTrigger.PlayConversation(Index));
}
```

this would require to make `op.Scaling` also an `IEnumerator`.

Comment: The part with the DOFControl.hasFinished is only once in the game since it happens only once when the game start. Other then that the idea what I want to do is in the NaviDialouge script to be able easy to  start each time another conversation from other scripts. And in my game when the conversation start first make the object scale up when scaling up has finished start a conversation when the conversation has ended scale down back the object.

Comment: It's a bit complicated since the op script is using the scaling script. It's just when scaling up/down from the op script it's also using other elements like light and stuff that's why I'm calling the scaling up/down from the op and not from the scaling.

Comment: And the conversation system I did is using indexs .

Comment: I know it's a lot of codes if I could upload somewhere part of the project. But the idea is that when there is a conversation with the navi the navi should scale up then start conversation then in the end scale down back.

Answer (score 1):

I didn't even read the whole of your scripts. Highly recommend you to use a tweening library for such stuff. You can easily scale, rotate, translate, blend colours and many more with these libraries. 
Take a look at [DoTween](http://dotween.demigiant.com/), with DoTween you can write scaling like this:

```cs
transform.DoScale(Vector3.one * 2, 1f).onCompelete( ()=>
    {
        print("Scaling finished!");
    }
```

But tweening is not all about setting callbacks, with tween you can animate your object programmatically.

You can check a quick tutorial about capabilities:
[YouTube Video](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=gkI7iQ23pw0)